# How to understand the return value of uxtaskgetstackhighlwatermark()

Tags: freertos, mcu

According to the official doc <FreeRTOS_Reference_Manual_V10.0.0>:
"*uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark() is used to query how close a task has come to overflowing the stack space allocated to it.*"

I'm using rtl8720, a 32-bits chip running FreeRTOS_v10.2.0.
I wrote a test program as follows, and main() function will call TestTaskEntry() :

```
static void TestStack()
{
    char buff[500] = {0};

    #if defined(INCLUDE_uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark) && (INCLUDE_uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark == 1)
    printf("\n\r[2] Min available stack size %d * %d bytes\n\r", uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark(NULL), sizeof(portBASE_TYPE));
    #endif

    return;
}

static void TestTask()
{
    #if defined(INCLUDE_uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark) && (INCLUDE_uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark == 1)
    printf("\n\r[1] Min available stack size %d * %d bytes\n\r", uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark(NULL), sizeof(portBASE_TYPE));
    #endif

    TestStack();

    #if defined(INCLUDE_uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark) && (INCLUDE_uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark == 1)
    printf("\n\r[3] Min available stack size %d * %d bytes\n\r", uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark(NULL), sizeof(portBASE_TYPE));
    #endif

    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

void TestTaskEntry(void)
{
    if(xTaskCreate(TestTask, ((const char*)"test task"), 500, NULL,
        tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 3 + PRIORITIE_OFFSET, NULL) != pdPASS) {
        printf("\n\rcreate stack failed\n\r");
    }
}
```

The printing of the program is as follows:

```
[1] Min available stack size 485 * 4 bytes

[2] Min available stack size 424 * 4 bytes

[3] Min available stack size 424 * 4 bytes
```

I think [1] should be closer to the task depth (500 * 4 bytes) of TestTask. But [2] and [3] should be 500 bytes smaller than [1], because there is a local array with a size of 500 bytes.
How should I understand the actual execution results of my program? Why is StackHighWater not the smallest remaining stack in TestTask history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your `buff` variable is optimized by the compiler because it is never used, so it does not need any stack. You can try to prevent optimization by writing `volatile char buff[500] = {0};`.
For testing purposes, I would also increase the stack size when calling `xTaskCreate`.

There is also a remarkable chapter for stack usage estimation in the FAQ: https://www.freertos.org/FAQMem.html#StackSize

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I used volatile char buff [500] = {0};  , and increase the stack depth to 1000, then Log output is:    
[1] Min available stack size 985 * 4 bytes    

[2] Min available stack size 860 * 4 bytes    

[3] Min available stack size 796 * 4 bytes    
        So volatile really works. In addition, I learned more about stack analysis from the link you shared. Thank you again!